# Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

1) –, Ну, давайте, давайте, давайте!..
Почему после "НУ" запятая.
Это одиночное деепричастие?
2) Что это сон или явь.
Где ставиться запятая и почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Ну" принято трактовать либо как (1) частицу, усиливающую то, что сразу после неё (ну давай), либо как (2) побудительное междометие, которое выделяется интонационно и знаками препинания (ну, давай - здесь "ну" действует независимо от "давай"). Поэтому здесь в зависимости от того, есть ли (нужна ли) при произнесении пауза, запятая либо ставится, либо не ставится.

Что это, сон или явь?

Здесь знаком препинания разделяются две формы одного и того же вопроса (Что это? Это сон или явь?). Знаки могут быть разными. В случае запятой вторая часть вопроса выражена как уточнение первой (предложены вероятные варианты ответа). Если поставить двоеточие, то спрашивающий как бы просит выбрать один ответ из двух. Если поставить тире, то такая запись отразит легкое недоумение: вопрос становится риторическим (спрашивающий не ждёт ответа, он знает его).

Comment: Частица или междометие - решает автор. Автор поставил запятую, значит - междометие.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае "ну" -  междометие, выражающее побуждение. Междометие "ну" интонационно отделяется от последующего слова и обособляется. В вашем примере нет деепричастия.